# The meta post preview does not have consistent styling applied to hyperlinks

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here how hyperlinks appear in the editor preview:

[image: markdown editor and preview]

But here is how they look once posted:

[image: actual post]

The blue styling needs to be applied to hyperlinks in the editor to match up with how they look when posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build